# Rest Client for multiple sequential requests

Tags: rest, postman, rest-client

Is there a tool available for making rest calls to api endpoints. My task is to sequentially run a list of commands where one command uses some response of previous command and runs. I checked postman which allows me to run multiple requests simultaneously using collections but how can I use a response and use it for the next post request and Automate the whole process? Or is there any other tool which would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In postman You can set environment variables with the results and then use them in the next requests.

Checkout out postman's docs. [chaining requests](http://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/)

Another way would be by using a simple javaScript in NodeJS.
Ex: (get the first github user´s follower in 2 chained requests):

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

fetch('https://api.github.com/users/github')
    .then(function(gituhubUser) {
        return gituhubUser.json();
    })
    .then(function(gituhubUserJSON) {
        return fetch(gituhubUserJSON.followers_url)
    })
    .then(function(followers) {
        return followers.json();
    })
    .then(function(followersJSON) {
       console.log(followersJSON[0].login);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Will check it and revert!